# WPF C# Foreach getting next value

Tags: c#, wpf, foreach, lambda, records

I got a list of records from database that i have retrieve like this in my CRUD class ( i am using entity framework and Model.question is my class which have CRUD codes in it):

```
        public IList<Model.questionhint> GetRecords(int listTask, int listActivity)
    {
        IList<Model.questionhint> lstRecords = context.questionhints.ToList();
        return lstRecords.Where(a => a.TaskID == listTask && a.ActivityID == listActivity).ToList(); 

    }
```

And this is how i call it from my xaml.cs :

```
 IList<Model.questionhint> lstQuestionHints = qh.GetRecords(taskID, activityID);

        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        foreach (Model.questionhint qhm in lstQuestionHints)
        { //Code here
        }
```

but in my database table , there is a column call questionNo , some records have same questionNo , activityID and taskID . some records have the same activityID and taskID but different questionNO . 
This is how my database table looks like :

[image]

At the moment , i can display each and every record nicely ( using foreach loop) but what i wanted is to group records of the same activityID , taskID and questionNo together in a line , now every record is seperated line by line like this :

[image]

i want it to be like

I [answer] to have a nap every afternoon

The sun [answer] not move round the earth.

I tried to do a group by query in CRUD ( i am using lambda expression) but it fail due to some igrouping and data shaping reasons ( not good in this ) , is there any other way to do this easily?

What i have in mind is by using foreach loop , but can i get the next value of questionNo ? for example in this loop the questionNo is 1 , i would like to check if questionNo in the next loop is the same , if not the same , i'll add it to next line but if its the same , i will add it to the same line. But i am not good with panels and stuffs since i am new to programming  as well as WPF/C# .

Would appreciate any help/solutions , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wouldn't try to do this in a single statement. You'd probably want to pre-process the data somewhat, because every question (e.g. single line) consists of an overlap of beginning content part, options part, and then ending part, spanning at least 2 records.

So, create a Model that would represent a part of the question, like so (just an example):

```
public abstract class QuestionPart {}

public class ContentPart : QuestionPart {
 // holds the content
}

public class OptionsPart : QuestionPart {
 // holds the options and the answer
}

public class Question{
   public List<QuestionPart> questionParts {get; set;}
}

public class YourViewModel{
   public List<Question> questions {get; set;}
}
```

Then, `Question` objects can be stacked vertically, and each `QuestionPart` within each `Question` can be wrapped (probably a `WrapPanel` would work here best) to chain into a question.

To collect the data into the collection of questions - you could do something like the following (I may have bugs - I haven't compiled it yet, but this should give you an idea):

```
List<QuestionPart> questionParts = lstQuestionHints.SelectMany((r) => ExtractQuestionParts(r)); // ExtractQuestionParts returns a list of 1 or more question parts from each record

var groupedQuestionParts = questionParts.GroupBy((r) => r.QuestionNo);

var questions = groupedQuestionParts.Select((g) => return new Question(g.Key, g.ToList()));
```

Now that you have the collection of `Questions` you could either create controls in code-behind (as you seem to want to do), or mock around with XAML and `ItemsControls` and `DataTemplates`, etc...

Hope it helps.